# Unity mid air movement with velocitychange

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have made a script for player movement in a 3D game in Unity.
I like how the movement works, but when I jump while moving, the player keeps moving in that direction at the same speed till it falls to the ground, which is the expected behavior for this script.
But I want to be able to move the player in the air slightly (not fully controllable.)
I'm imagining kinda like a minecraft like movement to be exact.

Any advice to improve this code would be greatly apprecciated.

This is my code.

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class VelocityMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    #region Variables

    public float speed;
    public float gravity;
    public float maxVelocityChange;
    public float jumpHeight;
    public float raycastDistance;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    #endregion

    private void Awake()
    {
        //gets rigidbody, freezes rotation of the rigidbody, disables unity's built in gravity system on rigidbody.
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
        rb.useGravity = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Jump system 
        if(Grounded())
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, CalculateJumpSpeed(), rb.velocity.z);
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        //Moves the player when on the ground.
        if (Grounded())
        {
            //Calculate how fast the player should be moving.
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(playerInputs.hAxis, 0, playerInputs.vAxis); 
            targetVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(targetVelocity);
            targetVelocity *= speed ;

            //Calculate what the velocity change should be
            Vector3 velocity = rb.velocity;
            Vector3 velocityChange = (targetVelocity - velocity);
            velocityChange.x = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.x, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
            velocityChange.z = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.z, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
            velocityChange.y = 0f;

            //applies a force equal to the needed velocity change
            rb.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

        }

        //Adds gravity to the rigidbody
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, -gravity * rb.mass, 0));
    }

    //Checks if player is on the ground
    private bool Grounded()
    {
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, raycastDistance);
    }

    //calculates how high the player should be jumping
    private float CalculateJumpSpeed()
    {
        return Mathf.Sqrt(2 * jumpHeight * gravity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    //check how big the movement is. Swap SomeSmallValue with a float like 0.1f
    float actualSpeed;
    Vector3 velocity;
    if(Grounded())
    {
         actualSpeed = speed;
         //HERE IT IS NOT, THIS DOESN'T MATTER
         velocity = rb.velocity
    }
    else{
         actualSpeed = speed * SomeSmallValue;
         //WITH THIS rb KEEPS THE SPEED IF ANY BUTTON IS PRESSED
         velocity = 0;
    }

    //Moves the player ALWAYS.
        //Calculate how fast the player should be moving.
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(playerInputs.hAxis, 0, playerInputs.vAxis); 
        targetVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(targetVelocity);
        //if Grounded == true the movement is exactly the same than before, because actualSpeed = speed. 
        //If Grounded == false, the movement is so light
        targetVelocity *= actualSpeed;

        //Calculate what the velocity change should be
        //I'VE PLACED THIS UP IN ORDER TO CALL Grounded() ONLY ONE TIME
        //Vector3 velocity = rb.velocity;
        Vector3 velocityChange = (targetVelocity - velocity);
        velocityChange.x = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.x, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
        velocityChange.z = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.z, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
        velocityChange.y = 0f;

        //applies a force equal to the needed velocity change
        rb.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);



    //Adds gravity to the rigidbody
    rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, -gravity * rb.mass, 0));
}
```

If your code is working fine, try something like this. Just moved the grounded condition. Now the movement works also at air time. We check with that grounded bool how big the movement is.

Comment: This code does slow down the player movement in the air,  but it stops the player instantly  when the key is released. I want the character to keep the velocity that it has when starting the jump, and then add some more force to it when the player is pressing a button. (keeping the same trajectory the player had and then adding a slight control to it is an easy way of describing what I want.)

Comment: Completely true I was wrong. Now it should work, you can see the new editions at the code because they're in caps

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to slow down what your movements do while mid air.
at least that is the case for left and right. 
If I did undersand you correctly, you would make an else{} after the if(Grounded())
and go from there, may make some float variable that acts as a multiplier for you left/right control while mid air, aswell as another float variable for forward and backwards. 
Inside that else you could just multiply you speed with the variables (depending on the axis) and you should get some form of slower movement there.

I hope that helped you out at least a bit.